# MIMO LMMSE detector: why 8x8's BER is better than 4x4?

Tags: mimo

I am simulating the MIMO linear detector algorithms including Matched Filter, Zero Forcing and Linear MMSE.

I simulated three configures: 4x4 ( 4 tx antennas 4 rx antennas ), 8x8 and 16x16.

For Matched Filter and Zero Forcing, 4x4's BER is better than 8x8's, 8x8's BER is better than 16x16's. But for LMMSE, I got the different result: 4x4's BER is worse than 8x8's, 8x8's BER is worse than 16x16's.

Is it right ?

[image]

I expanded the SNR range to 70dB, this is the result:

[image]

```
clear;
Nts = [4,8,16];
Nrs = [4,8,16];

N = 1e4;

SNRs = (-10:2:20);

BERs_MF = zeros(length(Nts), length(SNRs));
BERs_ZF = zeros(length(Nts), length(SNRs));
BERs_LMMSE = zeros(length(Nts), length(SNRs));

tic
for cc=(1:length(Nts))
    Nt = Nts(cc);
    Nr = Nrs(cc);
    
    for ee=(1:length(SNRs))
        SNR = SNRs(ee);
        Pnoise = 1/10^(SNR/10);
        NerrorMF = 0;
        NerrorZF = 0;
        NerrorLMMSE = 0;
        
        for ii=(1:N)
            x = 2*randi([0,1],Nt,1) - 1;
            H = 1/sqrt(Nt) * (randn(Nr,Nt) + 1j*randn(Nr,Nt))/sqrt(2);
            n = sqrt(Pnoise/2) * (randn(Nr,1) + 1j * randn(Nr,1));
            
            y = H*x + n;
            
            % matched filter
            x_hat = H'* y;
            x_hat = 2*(x_hat>0)-1;
            NerrorMF = NerrorMF + sum(x ~= x_hat);
            
            % zero forcing
            x_hat = (H'* H) \ H' * y;
            x_hat = 2*(x_hat>0)-1;
            NerrorZF = NerrorZF + sum( x ~= x_hat);
            
            % LMMSE
            x_hat = (H'*H + Pnoise * diag(ones(Nt,1)))\H' * y;
            x_hat = 2*(x_hat>0)-1;
            NerrorLMMSE = NerrorLMMSE + sum( x ~= x_hat);
        end
        
        BERs_MF(cc,ee) = NerrorMF;
        BERs_ZF(cc,ee) = NerrorZF;
        BERs_LMMSE(cc,ee) = NerrorLMMSE;
    end

    BERs_MF(cc,:) = BERs_MF(cc,:) /(Nt* N* 1.0);
    BERs_ZF(cc,:) = BERs_ZF(cc,:) /(Nt* N* 1.0);
    BERs_LMMSE(cc,:) = BERs_LMMSE(cc,:) /(Nt* N* 1.0);

end

toc;



figure();
semilogy(SNRs, BERs_MF(1,:), "k*--");
hold on;
semilogy(SNRs, BERs_MF(2,:), "b>--");
hold on;
semilogy(SNRs, BERs_MF(3,:), "rd--");
hold on;
% save('MIMO_detection_MF_4x4_8x8_16x16.mat','SNRs');
% save('MIMO_detection_MF_4x4_8x8_16x16.mat','BERs_MF','-append');

semilogy(SNRs, BERs_ZF(1,:), "k*-");
hold on;
semilogy(SNRs, BERs_ZF(2,:), "b>-");
hold on;
semilogy(SNRs, BERs_ZF(3,:), "rd-");
hold on;

% save('MIMO_detection_ZF_4x4_8x8_16x16.mat','SNRs');
% save('MIMO_detection_ZF_4x4_8x8_16x16.mat','BERs_ZF','-append');


semilogy(SNRs, BERs_LMMSE(1,:), "k*:");
hold on;
semilogy(SNRs, BERs_LMMSE(2,:), "b>:");
hold on;
semilogy(SNRs, BERs_LMMSE(3,:), "rd:");
hold on;

% save('MIMO_detection_LMMSE_4x4_8x8_16x16.mat','SNRs');
% save('MIMO_detection_LMMSE_4x4_8x8_16x16.mat','BERs_LMMSE','-append');

legend("4MF", "8MF", "16MF", "4ZF", "8ZF", "16ZF", "4LMMSE", "8LMMSE","16LMMSE");
ylim([0.00001,1]);
grid on;
```

Comment: I cann't find a bug. I think it is so because LMMSE is able to remove interference effectively and this ability may reverse the tendency. Imagine that with one receive antenna the interference cannot be removed with LMMSE, but with more receive antennas it may be removed more effectively. I cannot give a theoretical explanation and leave it to others.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! I'm wondering why the 4 and 8 antenna versions perform better for the MF and ZF versions than the 16 antenna version.  My intuition says that more antennas will give better performance (else why try?).

Comment: I don't have an answer but a couple observations: (1) the matched filters are performing weirdly, your plot is saying no matter how high the SNR is a matched filter can't achieve zero bit errors?, and (2) at high SNR I believe you should see the ZF and LMMSE performance be close to each other

Comment: @Engineer  , Yes, Matched Filter(MF) algorithm has an error floor ( minimum error probability ) because of interference from other antennas no matter how low noise there is.

Comment: @PeterK. Not "better" in the sense of error rate because the OP used multiple antennae to spatial multiplex several streams (`x = 2*randi([0,1],Nt,1) - 1;`), i.e. increase the data rate, instead of improving the diversity for a lower decoding error probability.

Comment: @AlexTP Doesn't that hold for all of them? I'm still missing the reasoning. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @PeterK. That holds for all of them. I just want to say that increasing the number of antennae does not necessarily result in a better error rate for spatial multiplexing mode. About the simulation of the OP, there is something not right. For instance, when AWGN noise is small enough (e.g. very high SNR), and as $N_t = N_r$, and as we know exactly the channel $H$, this is simply a full-rank system of linear equations at the receiver. Therefore, in this case, the number of antennae should have no impact, not like the simulation result at $\geq 50dB$

Comment: Also, there may be an SNR normalization issue. It seems that the OP wants to equally allocate power to $N_t$ antennae (by the construction of $H$) while keeping the unity power of $x$. If this is the case, increasing $N_t$ by a factor of two halves the SNR. Therefore, the gain is 3dB for 4x4 vs 8x8 and 8x8 vs 16x16. About the LMMSE, I have no explanation for the behavior but again I expect an identical BER at high SNR.

Comment: @AlexTP Thank-you. That makes sense.